# Select current location with cordova

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I need to give the app users to set there locations manually on the map like "Uber" App when i request a Taxi i have to move the pin to set the location where i need the Taxi in

I have a code which is get the current location without the ability to change this location manually but i don't need this.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
    var lat = pos.coords.latitude;
    var lng = pos.coords.longitude;
    alert("lat : "+lat+" lng : " +lng");
});
```

any idea

Comment: You might consider rewording you question. I'm not clear on what you're after. Particularly the bit where you say you have something but you don't need it

Comment: i need to give my users to set there locations manually like Uber App

Comment: in Uber App you can move the pin to your location.

Comment: i need to to do this exactly

Comment: You need a plugin like this one: https://github.com/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps

Comment: @MichaelMagdy have a look at the plugin, there is a function for moving the pin and getting the lat, lng.

Comment: @Joerg you are right thank you for your help